# Why do i get redirected url as a relative to the current url?

Tags: codeigniter-3

Why do i get this

> http://localhost/CI/index.php/:/localhost/CI/shoppingcart/buy/1/

when what i want is this....

> http://localhost/CI/shoppingcart/buy/1/

Comment: Check `base_url()` value in `APPPATH . 'config/config.php'`. Should be `http://localhost/CI/` in your case.

Comment: It's already been set but can't get rid of the problem

Comment: With scheme (i.e. starting with `http://`)? Also, post all relevant code. Read [here](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and find out how.